# Create a matrix out of several vectors

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have several 2D vectors, where the first column is an index (for example "timestamp") and the second column is the value.

In each for loop i get one of these vectors, and i want to merge them all into a large 2D matrix where the first column is the index, and each other column is a different value out of those original vectors.

For example:

```
v1 <- matrix(c(seq(1:10), rnorm(10)), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
v2 <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, rnorm(7)), nrow = 7, ncol = 2)
v3 <- matrix(c(11, 12, rnorm(2)), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

The reslut i would like is a 12x4 matrix:

first column is the 1:12, second column is the value of v1 according to timestamps 1:10, third column is the values of v2 only in places 1,2,3,6,7,8,9, fourth column is the values of v3 only in places 11, 12.
Where no value is available NULL will be placed.

Note that i want them all to be merged according to their timestamp.

Comment: not really something to do with your question but you're not closing the brackets in the right place to create v2 and v3...

Comment: Another thing: NULL cannot be placed in a matrix. NULL represents the NULL object which cannot be placed in an array. You probably want to fill in with NA. To illustrate the difference try the code `c(1, NA, NULL)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the "vectors" that were generated are called "vi", i being a number, you can do :

```
# get the names of all the "vectors" generated :
list_vec<-ls(pattern="^v\\d+$")

# get all unique timestamps (all unique values from 1st column of the different "vectors")
unique_timestamp<-unique(unlist(sapply(list_vec,function(x){get(x)[,1]})))

# create the matrix that will contain all results :
new_mat<-matrix(,nrow=length(unique_timestamp),ncol=length(list_vec)+1)
new_mat[,1]<-sort(unique_timestamp)
colnames(new_mat)<-c("timestamp",list_vec)

# finally, fill the matrix with the values in second column of the different "vectors", with respect to the timestamps    
new_mat[,2:ncol(new_mat)]<-sapply(list_vec,function(x,mat){
                                              x<-get(x)
                                              x[match(mat[,1],x[,1]),2]
                              },new_mat)

> new_mat
      timestamp          v1         v2         v3
 [1,]         1 -0.95467687 -1.2764675         NA
 [2,]         2 -0.82596352  0.8011679         NA
 [3,]         3  0.20617686  0.3820669         NA
 [4,]         4 -0.09122235         NA         NA
 [5,]         5  0.42571662         NA         NA
 [6,]         6 -0.11503517  1.2128891         NA
 [7,]         7  0.64854445  0.4053852         NA
 [8,]         8  0.22632685  0.7690795         NA
 [9,]         9 -1.52236147  0.3290537         NA
[10,]        10  0.19791912         NA         NA
[11,]        11          NA         NA -2.0296883
[12,]        12          NA         NA  0.1624292
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as i stated the vectors are given in a for loop, and i don't know beforehand how many will be or their lengths/timestamps. Therefore i need something more general, which at each for iteration add the new vector to the matrix and either enlarges the matrix, or locates the vector in the correct timestamps in the matrix.

Comment: @user3370773, with my answer, you can create your matrix as soon as your `for` loop ends. You don't need to know how many vectors there are, or their lengths, just how their names "look like". I don't think enlarging a matrix is a good solution as R will allocate more and more memory without releasing it at each step (I mean, for example, R allocates memory for a 2x20 matrix, then for a 3x25 matrix but the memory for 2x20 matrix will not be released).

Comment: Thank you very much. So your advice is to run the for loop on all vectors and call them with known names. Once the loop is done i should create the matrix according to all saved vectors. Correct?

Comment: @user3370773, you're very welcome and yes, that is what I would do. You can call your vectors "v1", "v2"... or "vector1", etc. (but in this case, you'll have to modify the pattern in the `ls` call of my answer), ie with the same pattern so that it is easy to "catch" them all with just one call and then, once every vectors are "there", you just create the global matrix.

Comment: Can you help me one more small thing, which is how to call the vectors with same pattern name. I usually would write something like v <- data. how do i make the name run according to the loop index?

Comment: @user3370773, you can use `assign` and the loop index : `assign(paste0("v",i),data)`, where `i` is your loop index

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have three vectors:

```
M <- matrix(NA, 12, 4)
M[,1]       <- 1:12   # Fill first column
M[v1[,1],2] <- v1[,2] # Fill second column
M[v2[,1],3] <- v2[,2] # Fill third column
M[v3[,1],4] <- v3[,2] # Fill fourth column
```

This should easily be generalized to arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: This works because "timestamps" are equals to the row numbers but this can result in weird stuff if "timestamps" are not consecutive numbers... this also can be a bit time consuming if there are, for example, 40 "vectors"...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qpcR/docs/cbind.na

Or below is an example

library(plyr)

```
>> x 
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 

>> y 
> [1] 34  5  6
```

> t(rbind.fill.matrix(matrix(x,nrow=1),matrix(y,nrow=1)))

```
  [,1] [,2] 
1    1   34 
2    2    5 
3    3    6 
4    4   NA 
5    5   NA 
6    6   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^v\\d+'))
Un <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(lst,`[`, ,1 ))))
cbind(timestamp=Un,sapply(lst, function(x) 
             ifelse(Un %in% x[,1], x[,2], NA)))
#    timestamp      v1         v2        v3
# [1,]    1 -0.21183360 -1.7427876        NA
# [2,]    2 -1.04159113 -1.3249530        NA
# [3,]    3 -1.15330756 -0.5479339        NA
# [4,]    4  0.32153150         NA        NA
# [5,]    5 -1.50012988         NA        NA
# [6,]    6 -0.44553326  0.9275789        NA
# [7,]    7  1.73404543 -0.7167693        NA
# [8,]    8  0.51129562 -1.7427876        NA
# [9,]    9  0.09964504 -1.3249530        NA
# [10,]   10 -0.05789111         NA        NA
# [11,]   11          NA         NA 0.9623997
# [12,]   12          NA         NA 1.5458846
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
v1 <- matrix(c(seq(1:10), rnorm(10)), nrow=10, ncol=2)
v2 <- cbind(c(1,2,3,6,7,8,9), rnorm(7))
v3 <- cbind(11:12, rnorm(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative, this time using `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(
  melt(lapply(mget(ls(pattern='^v\\d+')), as.data.frame), id.vars = "V1"), 
  V1 ~ L1, value.var = "value")
#    V1         v1          v2        v3
# 1   1 -0.6264538  1.51178117        NA
# 2   2  0.1836433  0.38984324        NA
# 3   3 -0.8356286 -0.62124058        NA
# 4   4  1.5952808          NA        NA
# 5   5  0.3295078          NA        NA
# 6   6 -0.8204684 -2.21469989        NA
# 7   7  0.4874291  1.12493092        NA
# 8   8  0.7383247 -0.04493361        NA
# 9   9  0.5757814 -0.01619026        NA
# 10 10 -0.3053884          NA        NA
# 11 11         NA          NA 0.9438362
# 12 12         NA          NA 0.8212212
```